# How to extract Kubernetes core metrics usage over time - metrics-server

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

I am using metrics-server in Kubernetes. How do I extract data relating to these core metrics:

- Number of pods running for each horizontal pod over a period of time
- CPU usage at certain points in time
- Number of failures / restarts over a period of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metrics-server has a [built-in API endpoint](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/resource-metrics-api.md#endpoints) where current usage of resources is reflected, and can be accessed with a [client library or proxying the master endpoints](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/api-machinery/api-group.md#client-side-implementation), for instance via `kubectl proxy` to expose the metrics in localhost or `k get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods" |jq .` to get a JSON result (with `jq` previously installed).

Keep in mind that [metric aggregation is not supported yet in this API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/resource-metrics-api.md#endpoints). Usually, these are [collected by a third-party agent and aggregated in a separate backend](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/monitoring_architecture.md#executive-summary), for example, [Stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/#about-skm) or [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-and-graph-kubernetes-metrics/).

Now, for the specific information you want to fetch from your cluster, there is no metric specific for the number of replicas created by the HPA. The system uses the *resource usage* metric in order to determine when to spawn more replicas of a deployment.

The CPU usage case seems very specific for already aggregated metrics, so you can use an aggregation solution for Kubernetes, like the ones mentioned before.

Finally, there is also not specific metric for failures and this specific information doesn't seem to be part of any [metrics pipeline](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/monitoring_architecture.md#executive-summary) but rather logging, as failures usually get logged but can be [aggregated afterwards](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) to create metrics.